# get roll around Y axis

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

How to get roll around Y axis?, I had achieved this when device is flat but not working when device hold on vertical, in front of face :( please help me with this.

```
float[] gravity = new float[3];
private float[] acceleration = new float[3];
//Above globel variables

if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            lowPassFilter.filter(event.values);
            System.arraycopy(acceleration, 0, this.acceleration, 0, acceleration.length);
            gravity = event.values.clone();

            double norm_Of_g = Math.sqrt(gravity[0] * gravity[0] + gravity[1] * gravity[1] + gravity[2] * gravity[2]);

            // Normalize the accelerometer vector
            gravity[0] = (float) (gravity[0] / norm_Of_g);
            gravity[1] = (float) (gravity[1] / norm_Of_g);
            gravity[2] = (float) (gravity[2] / norm_Of_g);
            int rotation = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(gravity[0], gravity[1])));

            tvXYZ.setText(String.format("X:%.2f, Y:%.2f, Z:%.2f\nArray Size: %d, Position in Array : %d",
                    gravity[0], gravity[1], gravity[2], list.size(), rotation));

            imageView.setRotationY(rotation);
        }
```